# how does i know of bottom of div in react js when website is in responsive view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, responsive-design

how do I know of the bottom of div in react JavaScript when the website is in responsive view

I want the bottom of the div point so I can use it for the scroll effect (onSroll)

Comment: You may expect this ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect the function helps you to know position of your node and its dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly:
const bottom = object.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)